# On which data should the lift be calculated i.e. Training set or Test set and why?

Tags: predictive-models, model, validation

On which data should the lift be calculated i.e. Training set or Test set and why?
What does the lift value 115% mean

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, we are more interested in how a model performs out-of-sample. With that being said, the lift should be calculated for the test set. The model built using only the training set that provides the greatest lift for the test set is the most preferred model.